# CompletionHandler doesn't work with closure in UIAlertController

Tags: swift

Have function to make alert like this:

```
var completionHandlers: [() -> Void] = []

 func alert(header: String,
               message: String,
               okButton: String,
               completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController.init(title: header,
                                                          message: message,
                                                          preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let ok: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: okButton,
                                               style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (_) in
                                                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                                                    self.completionHandlers.append(completionHandler)
                                                })
    }

    alert.addAction(ok)

    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

And here the usage of this function:

```
self.alert(header: "Warning", message: "The date of end must be selected", okButton: "Ок", completionHandler: {
                print("test")
            })
```

So the problem is, what my completionHandler dosent work at all. Even the test didnt printing in console. So how to correct make handler with closure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually call the completion handler you pass to `alert`. All you do is add it to an array.

There is no need for the `completionHandlers` array (at least not in the code you posted). And you do not need to dismiss the alert in the alert action.

Change the alert action to:

```
let ok: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: okButton, style: .default) { (_) in
    completionHandler()
}
```